# Нужны ли запятые? 1

Tags: пунктуация

*С западной стороны(,) на расстоянии 20 метров(,) расположена башня.* Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Comment: Начнём с того, что предложение неполное и непонятное. С западной стороны **чего?** На расстоянии **от чего?**

Comment: Разве есть разница?

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать как уточнение, то нужны.
(где?) С западной стороны, (где именно?) на расстоянии 20 метров, расположена башня.
Если не считать уточнением, то не нужны.